# CSS hover on div doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to make a CSS listen to a `:hover`.

I have the following CSS:

```
<style>
    .hidescroll
    {
    }    
        .hidescroll :hover 
        {
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
</style>
```

And html:

```
<div class="hidescroll" style="width:100%; height:100px; background-color:green;  overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:hidden;">
    <div style="width:300%; height:100px; background-color:red; ">abc</div>
</div>
```

I would expect the scrollbar to appear when I hover over the div. It doesn't. Why? (I tried to add `div` before `:hover` but that didn't help either.)

Comment: First, try removing the space between `.hidescroll` and `:hover`.

Comment: @Smuuf Didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline styles have a higher specificity. You either have to say `!important` on the hover declaration or move your styles away from inline. I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: Perfect! I moved the `overflow-x:hidden;` into the CSS and it works. Thanks. (I can't accept for another 6 minutes.)

Answer (score 1):

`style="..."` on the `<div class="hidescroll"` takes precedence over the separate css rule in the `<style>` block.

Since you already have a css rule for *hidescroll*, put those styles in there instead of putting them inline.

```
<style>
.hidescroll
{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}    
.hidescroll:hover 
{
    overflow-x: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="hidescroll">
    <div style="width:300%; height:100px; background-color:red;">abc</div>
</div>
```

It would be better to also put the styles for the inner div into a style rule.

Note — `!important` was meant to be used the *user agents*; used by the end-user to be able to override site styles, for example I use it to in my browser (with the *Stylebot* plugin) to fix font-size and contrast problems to make sites readable)